# AMQP Prevent automatic message reads

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm using Spring AMQP to listen to messages (configuration has `listener-container, service-activator, chain, bridge & aggregators`). At application startup AMQP starts reading messages which we don't want. I tried `auto-startup=false` but it isn't working. Am I missing anything?

Also, if it does work then how do I programmatically start them again? I tried `listenerContainer.start();`. What about aggregators & others?

## EDIT

Following is my config:

```
<rabbit:queue name="my_queue1" declared-by="consumerAdmin"/>
<rabbit:queue name="my_queue2" declared-by="consumerAdmin"/>
<rabbit:queue name="my_batch1" declared-by="consumerAdmin"/>

<int-amqp:channel id="myPollableChannel" message-driven="false" connection-factory="consumerConnFactory" queue-name="my_queue2"/>
<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter channel="myPollableChannel" auto-startup="false"/>

<int-amqp:channel id="myAggregateChannel" connection-factory="consumerConnFactory"/>
<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter channel="myAggregateChannel" auto-startup="false"/>

<int-amqp:channel id="myChannel" connection-factory="consumerConnFactory"/>
<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter channel="myChannel" auto-startup="false"/>

<int-amqp:channel id="myFailedChannel" connection-factory="consumerConnFactory"/>
<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter channel="myFailedChannel" auto-startup="false"/>

<rabbit:template id="genericTopicTemplateWithRetry" connection-factory="connectionFactory" exchange="my_exchange" retry-template="retryTemplate"/>

<rabbit:topic-exchange name="my_exchange" declared-by="consumerAdmin">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="my_queue1" pattern="pattern1"/>
            <rabbit:binding queue="my_queue2" pattern="pattern1"/>
        </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>

<int:handler-retry-advice id="retryAdvice" max-attempts="5" recovery-channel="myFailedChannel">
    <int:exponential-back-off initial="3000" multiplier="5.0" maximum="300000"/>
</int:handler-retry-advice>

<int:bridge input-channel="myPollableChannel" output-channel="myAggregateChannel">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="100" fixed-rate="5000"/>
</int:bridge>

<int:aggregator id="myBatchAggregator"
    ref="myAggregator" 
    correlation-strategy="myCorrelationStrategy" 
    release-strategy="myReleaseStrategy" 
    input-channel="myAggregateChannel" 
    output-channel="myChannel" 
    expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
    group-timeout="1000" />

<int:chain input-channel="myFailedChannel">
    <int:transformer expression="'Failed to publish messages to my channel:' + payload.failedMessage.payload" />
    <int-stream:stderr-channel-adapter append-newline="true"/>
</int:chain>

<int:service-activator input-channel="myChannel" output-channel="nullChannel" ref="myWorker" method="myMethod">
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain><ref bean="retryAdvice" /></int:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:service-activator>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="consumerConnFactory" requeue-rejected="false" concurrency="1">
    <rabbit:listener ref="myListener" method="listen" queue-names="queues1" admin="consumerAdmin" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

Comment: You have to share your configuration. Do not read messages from the AMQP there is really `auto-startup=false` on the Inbound Channel Adapter. That's enough. You don't need to worry about aggregator and others

Comment: Thanks Artem. Have added my configuration above. I'm using following function for switching it ON again:

`private void startMessageListeners() {
    final Map<String, AbstractMessageListenerContainer> containers =
            this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.class);
    if (containers != null && !containers.isEmpty()) {
        for (final AbstractMessageListenerContainer container : containers.values()) {
            if (!container.isRunning()) {
                container.start();
            }
        }
    }
}`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Thank you for the configuration!

Not sure why you need AMQP-bascked channels, but the main issue for you is exactly there.

But pay attention, the `<int-amqp:channel>` has `auto-startup="false"` option as well.

And you will be ready to receive data from the AMQP, you will need just `start()` those channels by their `id`.

Comment: Even after updating configuration like below:

`<int-amqp:channel id="myPollableChannel" message-driven="false" connection-factory="consumerConnFactory" queue-name="my_queue2" auto-startup="false"/>`

I'm still getting:
`[org.springframework.integration.amqp.channel.PollableAmqpChannel] (task-scheduler-1) Calling receive with a timeout value on PollableAmqpChannel. The timeout will be ignored since no receive timeout is supported.`

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Of course. Because you have to stop that `bridge` with `<poller>` for the `myPollableChannel`. Sorry, I missed that. ` message-driven="false"` means not `listener`-based. So, its lifecycle is controlled by the `poller` endpoint.

Comment: I got listener-based channels to start/stop & prevented `auto-startup` of `PollableAmqpChannel`. But I couldn't programmatically `start()` it. Config/code:
`<int:bridge input-channel="myPollableChannel" output-channel="xxxx" auto-startup="false">
<int:poller max-messages-per-poll="100" fixed-rate="5000"/>
</int:bridge>`
`final Object channel = this.applicationContext.getBean("myPollableChannel");
if (channel instanceof SmartLifecycle) {
return ((SmartLifecycle) channel).stop();
} else if (channel instanceof PollableAmqpChannel) {
//FIXME: Can't cast to Lifecycle. How do I stop it?
}`

Comment: No, if we are talking already about `<bridge>`, then it is `endpoint` and in that case you have to `start()` exactly that. So, just add an `id` to that `<bridge>` and use it as an identificator to get a bean for performing its `start()`